# Docker Image for NextJs ClientApp failing with an error Cannot find module '/app/server.js'

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, dockerfile

I am trying to create docker image for my nextjs application. It is working well in my local.

> ```
> My local node version is 16.14.0
> My local nextjs version is 12.x
> ```

I have nothing special in my next.config.js except reactStrictMode: true

My Dockerfile is here:

```
# PART 1 -------------------
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --frozen-lockfile
RUN npm i next@12.1.5
# PART 2 ----------------
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
# PART 3 ----------------
RUN npm run build
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
USER nextjs
EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I have then tried to troubleshoot this by going to interactive mode

```
docker run -it brij1111-portfolio sh
```

What I found there is just 3 items.

1. next.config.js (file)
2. node_modules (folder)
3. public (folder)

I did not find .next folder at all. However, in my public folder I can see I have all the images and other items as I have in my local development.
So, I feel that .next folder is not there and that could be a reason of I am getting following error.

[image]

For me, It looks like the .next folder did not get created at the first place (RUN npm run build) or it is not getting copied over (COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next)

To check this, I have commented on Part 3 and ran Part 1 & 2, and went to the container instance and that was an issue.

**I did not find the .next folder even though the RUN npm run build command was executed without any error.**

I am not sure what is the issue and How to move forward from here. any suggestion?

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the final `COPY --from=builder` lines copy the `server.sh` script into the final image.  That is, when you run `ls` the only things you see are those things you specifically `COPY`ed in.

Comment: `next build` vs `npm run build` is standard, are you using a seperate "build" comand in your `package.json`  can you post it?

Comment: Thanks to both of you guiding me. I haven't change anything in package.json file except adding some npm packages of the need and that means It has default scripts as "build": "next build", and "start": "next start". However, I found an answer on nextjs documentation. It says - In dockerfile we should use CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]. that means our final package is inside the node_modules/.bin/next and that is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It might that your `package.json` file, has the `dev: "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"` and you application doesn't have the server.js file as it is not created.. you should look into that.